# How do I import an IIS 6 metabase into iis7?

Tags: iis, iis-6, iis-7.5, metabase

Before my Windows 2003 box died, I made backups of the Metabase history as well as exported a backup to an MDO file.

I would like to import the entire file into IIS7 so that I don't have to re-create all of the site/domains and app pools manually.

Is there a tool or powershell command that will do this easily?

MSDeploy is not an option as the 2003 server is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a handy tool available where you can point it at an IIS6 metabase backup and tell it to reconstruct your sites and settings.

Your options are a bit limited:

- build a new Windows 2003/IIS6 server and restore from metabase backup. Once done export to IIS7 using msdeploy.
- write a script to parse the `.MD0` file (it's just XML) and rebuild your sites on IIS7. This does require a reasonable amount of knowledge about IIS6'S metabase structure and how to use IIS7's API's; however it is quite well documented.

Further reading:

> [IIS6 Metabase Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525644%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
>
> [IIS 7 How to Use Microsoft.Web.Administration](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/165/how-to-use-microsoftwebadministration/)
>
> [IIS 7 Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference)

If you only have a handful of sites then it might just be quicker to bite the bullet and recreate them manually in IIS7 MMC.

Comment: I ended up building it in a VM and going with your first suggestion.